# Change chevron color by replacing it in modifyCell with new sf symbol chevron.right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

Id like to use the system image `chevron.right` for my accessory icon and replace what is currently there so I can control the color.  Right now with `iOS 13+` the tint color is not updating like the text is, previous versions work.  I need this done in `objective c`, not swift, using the system image `sf symbol` `chevron.right`.

```
- (void)modifyCell:(UITableViewCell*)tableCell andIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Event *event = [self findDataInRow:[self findRow:indexPath]];

    if(event != nil)
    {
        EventsTableViewCell *eventTableCell = (EventsTableViewCell *)tableCell;

        if(eventTableCell != nil)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manipulate the color of the `accessoryView` of the dequeued `UITableViewCell` when you return the cell in:

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So in a simple datasource implementation.

```
@implementation XViewController

- (UIColor *)colorForIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSArray *colors = @[UIColor.redColor,UIColor.greenColor,UIColor.blueColor];
    return colors[index % 3];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}


- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello world";
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"pencil.slash"];
    UIImageView *accessory = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"pencil.and.outline"]];
    accessory.tintColor = [self colorForIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryView = accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 6;
}


@end
```

Pick your favoured system image instead of `"pencil.and.outline"` which is just there to prove that it isn't the standard chevron. Observe that the LHS cell image takes the view tint of `orange` and the accessory view on RHS takes any color that you wish.

[image]

Comment: The whole reason for using the chevron is because with iOS 13 the accessory icon color wasnt able to be changed anymore. This worked perfectly.  I had to wrap it in the `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` but its exactly what was needed.